# Difference between exit() and posix_kill(getmypid(), SIGKILL) in PHP

Tags: php, posix, exit, kill

Can someone explain difference between `exit()` and `posix_kill(getmypid(), SIGKILL)` in PHP code?

Answer (score 2):

From the [`exit()` docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php):

> Terminates execution of the script. **Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit() is called.**

SIGKILL, on the other hand, does not allow any cleanup to be done by the process receiving the signal.

> When sent to a program, SIGKILL causes it to terminate immediately. In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL#Usage)